# Getting Elm to read and write to a SQL database

Tags: sql, database, user-interface, elm

So I'm having trouble finding an Elm package that I can use to interface directly with a SQL database. I want write a UI in elm and then access a database to communicate with, both read and write. 
Do you have any suggestions? It seems like it is possible with something like Node but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Apparently I need to use a back-end like node.js. If this is correct this question can me marked off as completed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Elm is focused primarily at building front-end UI applications, and using it on the back-end in node is currently experimental.

If you want to write a UI application that connects to SQL server, you will most likely have to build a web server application which connects to the SQL database and exposes a JSON API that your Elm app will consume.

Comment: I was under the impression that node is the backend. How would you for instance go about to build an app like this? I don't mind using intermediaries. If i have to use java and elm + node + MySQL or whatever.

Comment: Yes, node can be used as a back-end web server. Using Elm inside node isn't mature or officially supported, so there's no easy way to connect Elm code directly to a SQL database.

Comment: Ok I get it now. Thanks.